# How to pass a Pipeline variable as boolean to a template?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to pass a Pipeline variable (`enable_datasync_job`) that I have defined using the UI:
[image]

to a template that is used within my main pipeline `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```
name: MyRepo.Deployment.$(date:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(rev:.r)

...

jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
...
      - template: azure-pipelines.yml@Common-YAML
        parameters:
          ...
          enable_datasync_job: $(enable_datasync_job)
```

The `Common-YAML` template defines that variable as `boolean`:

```
parameters:
...
  - name: enable_datasync_job
    type: boolean
    default: false
```

When I try to run my main pipeline, it currently breaks as it completes that I am not passing a boolean value to my template

[image]

I know that all pipeline variables as of type string. How do I convert that string to a boolean so that my template accepts it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the parameter that is in the `azure-pipelines.yml` also as `boolean` you will get a checkbox (boolean) instead of inputbox (string):
[image: example run]

You should be able to pass this along the `Common-YAML`.

### Example code

The `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
  - name: enable_datasync_job
    type: boolean
    default: false

extends:
  template: boolean.yml
  parameters:    
    enable_datasync_job: ${{ parameters.enable_datasync_job }}
```

The `azure-pipelines.yml`, without `extends`:

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
  - name: enable_datasync_job
    type: boolean
    default: false

steps:
 - template: boolean.yml
   parameters:
    enable_datasync_job: ${{ parameters.enable_datasync_job }}
```

The `boolean.yml` (`Common-YAML`):

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: enable_datasync_job
    type: boolean
    default: false

steps:
- script: |
   echo the value is ${{ parameters.enable_datasync_job }}
```

### The result

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have one question. Does the main pipeline need to `extend` the template?

Comment: It also works without `extend`, I updated the example

Comment: Thank you! I confirm that solved the problem! Appreciate it :)